# Use the date difference and change background color based on result

Tags: excel

I am trying to do some calculation with date and display an output based on that.

For example:

Cell [A1] has the value `10/20/2013`

Cell [A2] should display today's date and also have the following calculation:

```
If (DATEDIF(A1 and TODAY) is <= 30 days) {
     A2 displays today's date
     A2 text color is WHITE
     A2 cell Background should be RED
}
If (DATEDIF(A1 and TODAY) is > 30 days) {
     A2 displays today's date
     A2 text color is GREEN
     A2 cell background should be WHITE
}
```

I tried the following:

```
IF (DATEDIF(A1, TODAY(), "d"), A2.Interior.ColorIndex = 36, A2.Interior.ColorIndex = 31)
```

I am thinking I am missing something here... Can someone please assist me in completing the script.

[image]

Comment: Use the formula  + conditional formatting

Comment: Do I have to do nested IF statement?

Comment: one moment. posting an answer with screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in cell `A2`

`=IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1,"d")<=30,TODAY(),IF(DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1,"d")>30,TODAY(),""))`

Or you can also use this formula in Cell A2

`=IF(OR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"d")<=30,DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"d")>30),TODAY(),"")`

and then in the `Conditional Formatting | Use a formula to determine which cells to format`

use the formula

`=DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1,"d")<=30`

and

`=DATEDIF(TODAY(), A1,"d")>30`

And set the relevant format. This is how your conditional formatting will look once you set the rules.

[image]

And this is how your `A2` will behave

[image]

Comment: WOW... Thanks! that did entirely what I was requesting! Thanks again.

Comment: what would you compare `Today()` with?

Comment: I Updated my question with what error message image I am receiving in my spreadsheet. When I used the above code in a blank excel it worked but in my working spreadsheet it's giving me an error.

Comment: That is because you are using a date before todays date. You will have to amend the formula if you want to consider dates before today

Comment: Try this formula in `A2` For your worksheet, you will have to amend it accordingly...  `=IF(A1<TODAY(),IF(OR(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d")<=30,DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"d")>30),TODAY(),""),IF(OR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"d")<=30,DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"d")>30),TODAY(),""))`

Comment: Makes perfect sense! didn't even look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry one more thing, instead of displaying TODAY, can I display how many days left for expiration?

Comment: Yes. Subtract the date and show that. Ensure that the cell is formatted as number

Comment: Ohhhh I currently have it set as DATE... Got it.